# Spark Scala: create and use column in the dataframe on the same line

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I need a new column in a dataframe to then use in a different computation, my code looks similar to:

```
var df: DataFrame = ...
df = df.withColumn("new_col", df.col("a") / 2)
println(df.withColumn("res", df.col("b") + df.col("new_col")).head())
```

How to combine into a single line (and avoid using `var`)?

The problem is `df.col()` as I cannot simply do the following because `new_col` does not exist in `df` yet:

```
df.withColumn("new_col", df.col("a"))
  .withColumn("res", df.col("b") + df.col("new_col"))
  .head()
```

Is there some API I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$` to make a column instead of `df.col`; The former will infer the column from the new data frame instead of `df`:

```
df.withColumn("new_col", $"a")
  .withColumn("res", $"b" + $"new_col")
  .head()
```

Or:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
df.withColumn("new_col", col("a"))
  .withColumn("res", col("b") + col("new_col"))
  .head()
```